# How to determine if a node is a leaf node in libxml2?

Tags: python, libxml2

Consider this piece of xml:

```
...
<DataType>
 <name>AccountStatus</name>
 <description>This field indicates the account status</description>
 <ValidValue>
  <value>A</value>
  <description>Account is Active</description>
  <name>ACTIVE</name>
 </ValidValue>
 <ValidValue>
  <value>I</value>
  <description>Account is Inactive</description>
  <name>INACTIVE</name>
 </ValidValue>
</DataType>
<DataType>
 <name>
 ...
```

I would like to know if a given node is a leaf node or not.
For example, "name", "description" and "value" are leaf nodes.
"ValidValue" is not because it contains subelements.

This is what I tried:

```
import libxml2
doc       = libxml2.parseFile("data_types.xml")
xml_query = doc.xpathNewContext()
node_list = xml_query.xpathEval('/path/to/DataType')
for node in node_list:
    print '%s' % k.get_children()
    print '%s' % k.isText()
```

Somehow get_children() and isText() behave weirdly. isText() returns 0 for the "name" node (?), and I couldn't quite figurewhat to do with the output of get_children().

Surely I could hack something into another xpath query and figure it out, but I suspect there should be a very straight forward way to do this using `libxml2`, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `lxml` the wrapper around libxml?

Comment: Hi @Jon, I'm working in a somewhat restricted environment; `libxml2` is avaliable but `lxml` not.
I could install it locally but other people trying to run my code would have to the same, which I is something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have running python libxml2, but I can tell you a bit about libxml2 philosophy. Text contents is treated as a node, a node of type *text*. So you can't rely on children count with your meaning of *leaf node*.

I think you need a function that walks all the children nodes and tests if there is any node of type *element*. No *element* children means being a leaf.

Comment: Jarekczek's right.  Another example of child-counting problems: <name>first<!--test-->last</name> would have 3 children (text/comment/text), but I'm guessing you'd still consider it a "leaf".  Checking for the existence of element-type children is the only way.

Comment: I was hoping for something as simple as node.isLeaf(); so it looks like I have to implement it myself...